# Use a children method c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have those objects:

```
class A{
    public:
        void print();
}

class B : public A{
    public:
        void print();
}

class C : public A{
    public:
        void print();
}
```

The function print:

```
void A::print(){
    cout << "A" << endl;
}

void B::print(){
    cout << "B" << endl;
}

void C::print(){
    cout << "C" << endl;
}
```

Now I have a vector of A objects which can contain A B or C

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<m_vA.size(); i++)
{
    cout << m_vA[i]->print() << endl;
}
```

But each time the function returns A even if this is a B or C object

Thanks for the help

Comment: Note that a vector of pointers to A is very different than a vector of As.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not override the function. To do so, use "virtual" keyword while declaring this function in A class.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to make the member function *virtual*.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake, I read "Now I have a vector of A objects"

Comment: No problem, i skipped that statement, i only looked at the code

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: use `virtual` as the other answers indicate, so that you override the function, instead of hiding it.

Here's an excerpt from Herb Sutter's *Exceptional C++ - Item 21: Overriding Virtual Functions* which explains in more detail what is going on with your code:

> It's important to differentiate between three common terms:
>
> - To *overload* a function `f()` means to provide another function with the same name `f()` in the same scope but with different
>     parameter types. When `f()` is actually called, the compiler will try
>     to pick the best match based on the actual parameters that are
>     supplied.
> - To *override* a virtual function `f()` means to provide another function with the same name `f()` and the same parameter types in a
>     derived class.
> - To *hide* a function `f()` in an enclosing scope (base class, outer class, or namespace) means to provide another function with the same
>     name `f()` in an inner scope (derived class, nested class, or
>     namespace), which will hide the same function name in an enclosing
>     scope.

Because your various `print` functions are in nested scopes, and because you have not provided the `virtual` keyword, each function is *hiding* the functions of the same name in the base class(es):

```
class A{
    public:
        void print();
}

class B : public A{
    public:
        void print(); // Hides A::print()
}

class C : public A{
    public:
        void print(); // Hides A::print() and B::print()
}
```

So, when the compiler performs name resolution, it will look within the current scope (which is the class definition for the type from which you have called the function) and it will stop there because it will find a non-virtual function with the name `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism requires the use of the `virtual` keyword to declare that the method should be stored in a virtual table (*vtable*), and its implementation looked-up at runtime.
Note also that your class definitions need semicolons after the closing brackets.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void print() override
    {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    virtual void print() override
    {
        cout << "C" << endl;
    }
};
```

On a side note, the `virtual` keyword in the derived classes is not necessary (it's implicitly added in derived classes if the base class function is declared virtual), but good to use for readability and to avoid potential issues with the odd compiler that requires it. The `override` identifier is also not necessary, but forces the compiler to check that you are in fact overriding a virtual function that exists in the superclass. (I think override is only available in C++11).